# R: How to create a raster of probabilities from multiple rasters

Tags: r, probability, raster, spatial, weighted

In R, I need to create a `raster` of **probabilities** of 4 rasters (distance from road, slope, grass cover and tree cover). For each of these I have created a formula to calculate a weight. Unfortunately I cannot share the data. This function below is what I have tried to do so far but it is not working yet. It gives the error: `Non-numeric argument to mathematical function`. Any recommendations?

```
  probabilities_raster <- function(tc, gc, road, slp){
    
    # Create structure to hold data
    propxy_raster <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)
    ncell(propxy_raster)
    
    treecover <- (dnorm(tc, mean=0.7, sd=0.1))/(dnorm(0.7, mean=0.7, sd=0.1))  # not working
    
    grasscover <- (dnorm(gc, mean=0.3, sd=0.1))/(dnorm(0.3, mean=0.3, sd=0.1))  # not working
    
    road <- pnorm(-2+4*road)   # not working
    
    slope <- exp(-10*slp)  # this one works
    
    # Calculate weight
    weight <- treecover * grasscover * road * slope
    
    propxy_raster <- weight
    return(propxy_raster) 
  }
  
  raster_1 <- probabilities_raster(tc=raster_treecover, gc=raster_grasscover, road=raster_road, slp=
  raster_slope)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *minimal, self-contained reproducible example*. *Minimal* is also important, because your questions really should be:
"How can I use `dnorm` with a RasterLayer?"

```
library(raster)
tc <- raster() 
values(tc) <- runif(ncell(tc))
x <- dnorm(tc, mean=0.7, sd=0.1)
#Error in dnorm(tc, mean = 0.7, sd = 0.1) : 
#  Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I think what you are looking for is

```
x <- calc(tc, function(i) dnorm(i, 0.7, 0.3))
```

And with "terra" that would be

```
library(terra)
tc <- rast() 
values(tc) <- runif(ncell(tc))
x <- app(tc, \(i) dnorm(i, 0.7, 0.3))
```